# Правильно отобразить контент в нужной категории section

Tags: php, html, angularjs

Есть код, который отображает разные блоки section **flex-fluid-container** для разных категорий, мне нужно чтобы в категории **settings** отображался section с **id="admin"**,
а в остальных категориях section id="admin" скрывался и не влиял на отображение, мой код:

.........

```
        <div class="categories-list">
            <div class="category" ui-sref=".trash" ui-sref-active="open" ed-trash-droppable><i class="icon icon-trash"></i> <span class="text">{{:: 'trash' | translate }}</span></div>
            <div class="category" ui-sref=".recent" ui-sref-active="open"><i class="icon icon-clock"></i> <span class="text">{{:: 'recent' | translate }}</span></div>
            <div class="category" ui-sref=".favorites" ui-sref-active="open"><i class="icon icon-star-filled"></i> <span class="text">{{:: 'favorites' | translate }}</span></div>
            <div class="category" ui-sref=".settings" ui-sref-active="open"><i class="icon icon-cog"></i> <span class="text">{{:: 'settings' | translate }}</span></div>
        </div>

        <div class="ad-container" ng-if="ad1" ng-bind-html="ad1"></div>

        <space-usage></space-usage>
    </section>

    <section id="middle-col">
        <section class="flex-fluid-container">
            <div class="middle-col-flex flex-fluid" ng-controller="ItemsController" ng-file-drop drag-over-class="dragover" ng-file-change="upload($files)" ng-multiple="true" allow-dir="true">

                <div class="sub-nav">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline folder-path">
                        <li ng-click="folders.open(folder)" ng-class="{ selected: folders.selected.name === folder }" ng-repeat="folder in folders.selected.path.split('/')">
                            <i class="icon icon-folder"></i> {{folder}}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="action-buttons">
                        <md-button ng-if=":: isSmallScreen" class="left-col-toggler">{{:: 'Folders' | translate }} <i class="icon icon-folder"></i></md-button>
                        <md-button id="more-options" ed-more-options-menu ng-disabled="!selectedItems.getLength()">{{:: 'actions' | translate }} <i class="icon icon-ellipsis-vert"></i></md-button>
                        <div class="dropdown">
                            <md-button data-toggle="dropdown">{{:: 'sort' | translate }} <i class="icon icon-sort-name-up"></i></md-button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li ng-click="changeOrder('name')" ng-class="{ selected: order.prop == 'name' }"><a href="" translate>name</a></li>
                                <li ng-click="changeOrder('-file_size')" ng-class="{ selected: order.prop == '-file_size' }"><a href="" translate>sizeBigFirst</a></li>
                                <li ng-click="changeOrder('file_size')" ng-class="{ selected: order.prop == 'file_size' }"><a href="" translate>sizeSmallFirst</a></li>
                                <li ng-click="changeOrder('-created_at')" ng-class="{ selected: order.prop == '-created_at' }"><a href="" translate>dateUploaded</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <md-button ng-click="toggleSelectedView()">{{:: 'view' | translate }} <i ng-class="selectedView === 'grid' ? 'icon-th' : 'icon-th-large'" class="icon"></i></md-button>
                        <md-button ed-toggle-info-panel ng-class="{ active: rightPanel.open }">{{:: 'activity' | translate }} <i class="icon icon-info-circled"></i></md-button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="ad-container" ng-if="ad2" ng-bind-html="ad2"></div>

                <div ui-view class="files-view" afkl-image-container items-selectable infinite-scroll="paginateFiles()"></div>
                <div id="files-spinner" ng-if="ajaxProgress.files"><md-progress-circular md-mode="indeterminate"></md-progress-circular></div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="flex-fluid-container" id="admin">
            <div class="flex-fluid" ui-view></div>
        </section>
    </section>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Предложу костыльное решение. Если вы открываете через нажатие на

> ui-sref=".settings"

Новую url. например myapp/settings, то в контроллере можете сделать проверку url, и если он совпадает то показывать. Делается это через ng-if.

```
> app.controller ('ItemsController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
>     $scope.AdminView = function () {
>       if (window.location.hash == "#!/myapp/settings") {
>        return true
>       } else {
>        return false }
>       }  
   }]);
```

Вот уже ваш код.

```
    <section class="flex-fluid-container" ng-if="AdminView()" id="admin">
        <div class="flex-fluid" ui-view></div>
    </section>
```